# Create a has_many association where a condition applies to the primary table in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I've got `authentications` which have many `groups` using `uid` as the primary_key and `organizer_id` as the foreign_key, no problem.

But `uid` is unique scoped to the `provider` attribute. I want to make sure my association only fetches `groups` where `authentication.provider == 'meetup'`. I tried:

```
has_many :groups, :primary_key => "uid", :foreign_key => "organizer_id", :conditions => {:provider => "meetup"}
```

But this is just trying to find all `groups` with `provider == "meetup"`

How can I specify a condition on the primary table `authentications`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
has_many :groups, :primary_key => "uid", :foreign_key => "organizer_id", :include => :authentication, :conditions => {:authentication => {:provider => "meetup"}}
```

Updated:

If Group **belongs_to** Authentication with "organizer_id" as foreign_key then just:

```
Group.includes(:authentication).where(:authentication => {:provider => "meetup"})
```

Comment: Returns: `Failure/Error: @authentication.groups.should include(@group) }
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: authentication.provider:`

Comment: This association belongs to authentications? if so, there is something strange in association logic or i missed something. Why you search groups which belongs to just one(?) authentication with authentication conditions? what if authentication doesn't match? Show your models to be clear with it...

Comment: Ok...true. I can just do that from the side of the groups. I just wanted to see if there was an elegant way to make it work with an association. I suppose I can also write a method for `Authentication` called `groups`